Can't retrieve data from state using Pinia with Setup function
I'm trying to get over the composition API and Pinia with Vue3.
I'm making fetch data from store.My issue is when i add response data to character(state) in fetchCharacterById(action) but when i check character(state) it is empty.is this a bug or any ideas where I'm wrong in the process?
useFetchAPI.js
import axios from "axios";
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
import { computed, ref } from "vue";


export const useFetchAPI = defineStore('fetchAPI',()=>{

       let  characters = ref([])
       let character = ref({})
       let loading = ref(false)
       let errorMessage = ref('')

        let getCharacters = computed(()=>characters.value)
        let getCharacterById = computed(()=>character.value)

        let fetchCharacters = async()=>{
            loading.value = true
             await axios.get('https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character')
            .then(res=>{
                characters.value=res.data.results
                loading.value = false
            }).catch(err=>{
                errorMessage.value=err.errorMessage
                loading.value=false
            })
        }

        let fetchCharactersByFilter = async(input,status,gender,species)=>{
            loading.value = true
             await axios.get(`https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/?name=${input}&status=${status}&gender=${gender}&species=${species}`)
            .then(res=>{
                characters.value=res.data.results
                loading.value = false
            }).catch(err=>{
                errorMessage.value=err.errorMessage
                loading.value=false
            })
        }

        let fetchCharacterById = async(id)=>{
            loading.value = true
             await axios.get(`https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/${id}`)
            .then(res=>{
                console.log(res.data)
                character.value = res.data
                loading.value = false
                console.log(character.value)
            }).catch(err=>{
                errorMessage.value=err.errorMessage
                loading.value=false
            })
        }
        
        return {characters,character,loading,errorMessage,getCharacters,getCharacterById,fetchCharacters,fetchCharactersByFilter,fetchCharacterById}
})

CardDetail.vue
<template>
<div>
  
  <Spinner v-if="fetchAPI.loading"/>
  <Error v-else-if="fetchAPI.errorMessage" :errorMessage="fetchAPI.errorMessage" />
  <div
    class="max-w-sm mx-auto overflow-hidden bg-white rounded-lg shadow-lg mt-20">
    <div class="relative">
      <img class="w-full h-48 object-cover"
        :src="fetchAPI.getCharacterById.image"
        alt="Profile Image"/>
    </div>
       <ul class="px-6 py-4">
            <li><span class="font-semibold">Name </span><span class="text-gray-600">{{ fetchAPI.getCharacterById.name }}</span></li>
            <li><span class="font-semibold">Gender </span><span class="text-gray-600">{{ fetchAPI.getCharacterById.gender }}</span></li>
            <li><span class="font-semibold">Location </span><span class="text-gray-600">{{ fetchAPI.getCharacterById.location.name }}</span></li>
            <li><span class="font-semibold">Origin </span><span class="text-gray-600">{{ fetchAPI.getCharacterById.origin.name }}</span></li>
            <li><span class="font-semibold">Species </span><span class="text-gray-600">{{ fetchAPI.getCharacterById.species }}</span></li>
       </ul> 
    <div class="px-6 py-4">
      <span
        class="inline-block px-2 py-1 font-semibold text-teal-900 bg-teal-200 rounded-full"
        >{{ fetchAPI.getCharacterById.status }}</span>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
</template>

<script setup>
import Spinner from './Spinner.vue'
import Error from './Error.vue'
import { useFetchAPI } from "../store/useFetchAPI";
import { onMounted } from 'vue';


const props = defineProps({
      id:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
      }
  })

  const fetchAPI = useFetchAPI();
  console.log('fetch',fetchAPI.getCharacterById)

  onMounted(()=>{
    fetchAPI.fetchCharacterById(props.id)
  })

</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
</style>


Where is your problem exactly? At which line can you see that character is empty?

my problem is character(state) is empty and when i call getCharacterById from CardDetail , the result is empty

I mean which line of code are you doing this?
Because I can already tell your console.log('fetch',fetchAPI.getCharacterById) obviously prints undefined since it's executed before you fetch the character in the onMounted hook.

Your implementation appears to be working as expected from my side.
Link to the pinia playground: https://play.pinia.vuejs.org/...
App.vue
<script setup>
  import { useFetchAPI } from "./useFetchAPI";
  const fetchAPI = useFetchAPI();
  import { onMounted } from 'vue';

  console.log('fetch',fetchAPI.getCharacterById)

  onMounted(()=>{
    fetchAPI.fetchCharacterById(1)
  })

</script>

<template>
<div>
  <div
    class="max-w-sm mx-auto overflow-hidden bg-white rounded-lg shadow-lg mt-20">
    <div class="relative">
      <div class="w-full h-48 object-cover">
        {{fetchAPI.getCharacterById.id}}
      </div>
    </div>
       <ul class="px-6 py-4">
            <li><span class="font-semibold">Name </span><span class="text-gray-600">{{ fetchAPI.getCharacterById.name }}</span></li>
            <li><span class="font-semibold">Gender </span><span class="text-gray-600">{{ fetchAPI.getCharacterById.gender }}</span></li>
            <li><span class="font-semibold">Location </span><span class="text-gray-600">{{ fetchAPI.getCharacterById.location }}</span></li>
            <li><span class="font-semibold">Origin </span><span class="text-gray-600">{{ fetchAPI.getCharacterById.origin }}</span></li>
            <li><span class="font-semibold">Species </span><span class="text-gray-600">{{ fetchAPI.getCharacterById.species }}</span></li>
       </ul> 
    <div class="px-6 py-4">
      <span
        class="inline-block px-2 py-1 font-semibold text-teal-900 bg-teal-200 rounded-full"
        >{{ fetchAPI.getCharacterById.status }}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</template>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
</style>

useFetchAPI.js
import { defineStore } from 'pinia' import { computed, ref } from 'vue'

export const useFetchAPI = defineStore('useFetchAPI',()=>{

    const charactersData = [
        { id: 1, name: "John Doe", status: "Alive", gender: "Male", location: "Earth", origin: "Earth", species: "Human" },
        { id: 2, name: "Jane Doe", status: "Alive", gender: "Female", location: "Mars", origin: "Moon", species: "Human" },
        // Add more character objects as needed
    ];

    const characters = ref([]);
    const character = ref({});
    
    let loading = ref(false)
    let errorMessage = ref('')

    let getCharacters = computed(()=>characters.value)
    let getCharacterById = computed(()=>character.value)

    let fetchCharacters = async () => {
        loading.value = true;
        try {
            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 100));

            characters.value = charactersData;
            loading.value = false;
        } catch (err) {
            errorMessage.value = err.message;
            loading.value = false;
        }
    }

    let fetchCharactersByFilter = async (input, status, gender, species) => {
        loading.value = true;
        try {            
            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 100));

            characters.value = charactersData.filter(character => {
                return (input ? character.name.includes(input) : true) &&
                    (status ? character.status === status : true) &&
                    (gender ? character.gender === gender : true) &&
                    (species ? character.species === species : true);
            });
            loading.value = false;
        } catch (err) {
            errorMessage.value = err.message;
            loading.value = false;
        }
    }

    let fetchCharacterById = async (id) => {
        loading.value = true;
        try {
            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 100));

            character.value = charactersData.find(character => character.id === id);
            loading.value = false;
        } catch (err) {
            errorMessage.value = err.message;
            loading.value = false;
        }
    }
    
    return {characters,character,loading,errorMessage,getCharacters,getCharacterById,fetchCharacters,fetchCharactersByFilter,fetchCharacterById} })

Please verify that the following is functioning correctly:

TypeScript does not interfere with execution.

Data is fetched correctly using axios (you can add logging to the store itself to see if you receive the data).

Ensure that the props are correctly passed into the component here:
const props = defineProps({
      id:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
      }
  })




thanks bro.I'm going to verify that
